# Jest inherit tests from base class to derived sub-classes

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, inheritance, jestjs

I am working on unit tests for an angular app that uses abstract classes in many places.

What I am trying to get around is, to have to write tests for basic functionality into each implementation and adapt those tests everywhere everytime they need to change. I have been through the jest documentation, but either I have overlooked such an option, or I am searching for the wrong terms.

Here is an simplified use case, where I do have an abstract base class, that provides some functionality and some required function headers like this:

```js
export abstract class BaseComponent {
  let member: number = 0;

  abstract foo(): void;
  bar(param: number): string {
    this.member = param;
    return 'number: '+ param;
  }
}
```

and I have multiple implementations of that base, that implement missing methods and may change existing functionality:

```js
export class OneComponent extends BaseComponent {
  foo(): void {
    this.member = 1;
  }
}

export class TwoComponent extends BaseComponent {
  foo(): void {
    this.member = 2;
  }
  bar(param: number): string {
    this.member = 0;
    return 'number: '+ param;
  }
}
```

**Is there a way** to implement tests for the base class, that can be reused for each of the sub-classes??

```js
describe('BaseComponent', (instance: <T extends BaseComponent>) => { // ???
  it('should set member', () => {
    instance.foo();
    expect(instance.member).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should set member and return string', () => {
    const result = instance.bar(5);
    expect(instance.member).toBeTruthy();
    expect(result.lenght).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});

describe('OneComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    instance = new OneComponent();
  });
  // implement tests from BaseComponent above
  jest.magic('BaseComponent', instance); // ??

  // add another test
  it('should set member to 1', () => {
    instance.foo();
    expect(instance.member).toBeEqual(1);
  });
});

describe('TwoComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    instance = new TwoComponent();
  });
  // implement tests from BaseComponent above
  jest.magic('BaseComponent', instance); // ??

  // override existing tests
  it('should set member and return string', () => {
    const result = instance.bar(5);
    expect(instance.member).toBeEqual(0);
    expect(result.lenght).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

a jest run should show 3 positive tests for OneComponent (2 from the base + 1 additional) und 2 positive tests for TwoComponent (1 from the base + 1 overwritten).

thanks in advance.

Comment: I write a test where my base class is, and in the test create a test class of the abstract class. I then test what ever public functions I need to with this test class.  When I extend that base class in other modules, I do not repeat the tests of the functions in the base class, as they are already tested.  This does not hurt code coverage as the base class functions are not in the extended class. If I override a function, then I write a test for that function.

Comment: I understand. the problem is, that in my case an "empty" implementation would not be runable - I would need to have at least some logic in there for a proper tests run. see the `foo()` method above: the member variable is not initialized anywhere else, imagine that other methods/tests require that initialization. so I would need to run that same tests on different target components.

Comment: You still have Typescript, so you can import tests.  Write a standard file, ignore it from your project, and then import the code into the test file(s).

Comment: I am not sure if I can follow you. how can I inherit from tests coded outside a class as using `describe()` and `it()` ?

Comment: import { commontest } from 'a'      describe(''. () => {  a(); } );    You import your function, in the describe, you call the function. The function has the expects in the code. Same as simply adding the function in your file, and calling functions to perform common tests.